# ListView and ArrayAdapter with ConstraintLayout crashes the app

Tags: android, listview, android-constraintlayout

It works perfectly with linear layout but when I choose `ConstraintLayout` it doesn't work, I don't know why the app crashes

**NumbersActivity.java**

```
package com.example.bharat.learnmiwok;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;  

public class NumbersAct extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_numbers);

    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    words.add("one");
    words.add("two");
    words.add("three");
    words.add("four");
    words.add("five");
    words.add("six");
    words.add("seven");
    words.add("eight");
    words.add("nine");
    words.add("ten");

            ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, words);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);



    listView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
  }
}
```

**activity_numbers.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.bharat.learnmiwok.MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/list"
android:orientation="vertical">
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Thank you

Comment: there is no `R.id.list` (ListVIew) in your layout hence crash

Comment: +1 Pavneet_Singh strange Android Studio did not pick it up as an error? usually does when I make such mistakes

Comment: paste your error here

Comment: There IS an id with list

Comment: you are casting the id list with Constraint layout You should hav a list view in Constaraint layout with id list

Comment: @Mercato AS can only check missing layout. Not missing id. May be there is an id called `list` but inside another layout

Comment: @nhoxbypass AS can also check bad casting to wrong class type - at least it has done so multiple times for me in this exact kind of situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a `ListView` with id `list` in your layout. Remove/Change the `id` from your ConstraintLayout, add a listview and try again.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</ListView>
```

Your ConstraintLayout is not a ListView.

Comment: well in this case id list from Constraint layout needs to be removed

Comment: This works, In linear layout I didn't need to add list view, So why in Constraint layout?

Answer (score 0):

Probably on this line you getting crash

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
```

You tried to cast ConstraintLayout to ListView

Comment: probalbly means you are not sure?

Comment: and i don't think so you can later set adapter on constraint layout

Comment: @AbdulWaheed The questioner did not mention about crash log first time

Comment: Then it must be the comment rather than an answer

Comment: @AbdulWaheed Sorry, it's not your decision. So my answer is could be accepted, at least it's helpful.

Comment: @Blackkara please, don't take it personally. I have seen many answers downvoted with these words maybe, probably and etc

Answer (score 0):

You are using this:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
```

to find a ConstraintLayout. Try this instead:

```
ConstraintLayout listView = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
```

This would only resolve your crash, but it's best to use a listView or contain one into the ConstraintLayout to achieve your goal.